# Rails 4 image-path, image-url and asset-url no longer work in SCSS files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4

Are we supposed to use something else aside from `image-url` and others in Rails 4? They return different values that don't seem to make sense. If I have `logo.png` in `/app/assets/images/logo.png` and I do the following, this is what I get:

```
image-url("logo.png") -> url("/images/logo.png") #obviously doesn't work
image-path("logo.png") -> "/images/logo.png"
asset-url("logo.png") -> url("/logo.png")
```

Of course none of these work because they need at least `/assets` in front.

***UPDATE***: Actually, I just noticed, how do I access images in Rails 4? I have an image at `/app/assets/images/logo.png`. But if I go to any of the following URLs, I still don't see my image:

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/logo.png
http://localhost:3000/assets/images/logo.png
http://localhost:3000/logo.png
http://localhost:3000/images/logo.png
```

***UPDATE 2***: The only way I can bring up my `logo.png` is by moving it into the `/app/assets/stylesheets` directory and then pulling up:

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/logo.png
```

Comment: Try this: `asset_path("logo.png", image)`

Comment: @depa - that simply converted to "/logo.png", which does not bring up my image.

Comment: Are you using that helper inside a `.css` file or in a `.css.scss` file?

Comment: @depa - not using any helper. I think this is a bigger problem of assets just not working for my images folder

Comment: Yes, `asset_path` is a helper - https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#features

Comment: @depa - oh I see what you're asking. It's inside a `.css.scss` file

Comment: Not sure it'll help, but the `assets/logo.png` path will work only on development. If you're trying that on production you have to add the fingerprint to the file name. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care

Comment: @depa - I'm in development

Comment: I just tested that with a newly generated Rails 4 app. I created the `assets/images` directory, put an image in there and the standard `/assets/filename.png` path worked right off the bat.

Comment: @depa - wow... what did I do wrong? I have a standard images directory. it all works if I move `filename.png` into the `stylesheets` directory... even then though the `image-url` type helpers don't work properly.

Comment: Is it a brand new app or an upgraded one? Perhaps your `config.assets.paths` array is messed up?

Comment: @depa - brand new app...

Comment: @depa - yes, 4.0.0.rc1

Comment: did you do bundle exec assets:precompile

Comment: You're trying to run in Heroku?

Answer (score 119):

I just had this issue myself.
3 points that will hopefully help:

- If you place images in your `app/assets/images` directory, then you should be able to call the image directly with no prefix in the path. ie. `image_url('logo.png')`
- Depending on where you use the asset will depend on the method. If you are using it as a `background-image:` property, then your line of code should be `background-image: image-url('logo.png')`. This works for both less and sass stylesheets. If you are using it inline in the view, then you will need to use the built in `image_tag` helper in rails to output your image. Once again, no prefixing `<%= image_tag 'logo.png' %>`
- Lastly, if you are precompiling your assets, run `rake assets:precompile` to generate your assets, or `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` for production, otherwise, your production environment will not have the fingerprinted assets when loading the page.

Also for those commands in point 3 you will need to prefix them with `bundle exec` if you are running bundler.

Comment: Another point is to read the documentation http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html. Also can you see in the Web Developer Debug of your browser if the images are being loaded?

Comment: Now this is how you write an answer. Each scenario. Predicting the "what ifs", no loose ends. A mark of someone who has "seen combat" (really worked through the problem).

Comment: I've been bitten by missing RAILS_ENV=production on several occasions.

Answer (score 65):

Your first formulation, `image_url('logo.png')`, is correct. If the image is found, it will generate the path `/assets/logo.png` (plus a hash in production). However, if Rails cannot find the image that you named, it will fall back to `/images/logo.png`.

The next question is: why isn't Rails finding your image? If you put it in app/assets/images/logo.png, then you should be able to access it by going to `http://localhost:3000/assets/logo.png`.

If that works, but your CSS isn't updating, you may need to clear the cache. Delete `tmp/cache/assets` from your project directory and restart the server (webrick, etc.).

If that fails, you can also try just using `background-image: url(logo.png);` That will cause your CSS to look for files with the same relative path (which in this case is /assets).

Comment: Just to jump on this, I was bitten by using double quotes on the image path instead of single quotes. You much use single quotes with the asset helpers in the css/scss files.

Comment: i am getting "undefined local variable or method `image'"

Comment: Is it possible you accidentally put a space before the word image?

Answer (score 10):

I just found out, that by using `asset_url` helper you solve that problem.

```
asset_url("backgrounds/pattern.png", image)
```

Comment: I got `undefined local variable or method 'image'` error.

Comment: Maybe something changed on rails, this answer is old! 
You can try `asset_path("<your_path>", type: :image)`

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem, trying to add a background image with inline css. No need to specify the images folder due to the way asset sync works.

This worked for me:

```
background-image: url('/assets/image.jpg');
```

Comment: Thanks, I was doing `assets/img.jpg` or `../assets/img.jpg` which obviously doesn't work in any directory. `/assets/img.jpg` does. TY

Answer (score 5):

Rails 4.0.0 will look image defined with `image-url` in same directory structure with your css file.

For example, if your css in `assets/stylesheets/main.css.scss`, `image-url('logo.png')` becomes `url(/assets/logo.png)`.

If you move your css file to `assets/stylesheets/cpanel/main.css.scss`, `image-url('logo.png')` becomes `/assets/cpanel/logo.png`.

If you want to use image directly under assets/images directory, you can use `asset-url('logo.png')`

Answer (score 5):

for stylesheets:
  url(asset_path('image.jpg'))

Comment: What's the main difference between `url(asset_path('image.jpg')`, `url('image.jpg')` and `image-url('image.jpg')`? I'm working with ***Rails 5.0.0.1*** and `url()` works fine in ***SCSS*** files and in ***html.erb*** files I use `asset_path()` so I'd like to know the correct way to go. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `asset_path` add to image file a digest appendix. It's actually for production, after every deploy the a digest appendix will be changed and user's browser will download new version of images.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone arrives looking for how to generate a relative path from the **rails console**

```
ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
image_path('my_image.png')
=> "/images/my_image.png"
```

Or the **controller**

```
include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
image_path('my_image.png')
=> "/images/my_image.png"
```