# Rails4: image_url not generating digest in scss

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I can't understand why my css file is not appending digests to my assets with the helper method `image_url`

My assets are correctly precomiled, and files do contain the digest. I also can access them (with the digested url) manually. And most strange thing is that in the beginning it was working.

here's my configs:

```
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.version = '1.0'
  config.serve_static_assets = false #also tried true
```

here's my application.css:
 *= require_tree .

here's the common.scss file, used for including an image:

```
body{
    background: image_url('bg.jpg');
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

The images, as well as the stylesheets are in a subfolder inside assets/images and assets/stylesheets.

here my gems:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
```

I'm deploying with capistrano, but I don't think this is a capistrano related problem, assets are well compiled.

**EDIT**
What i've (unsuccessfully) tried until now:

```
image-url('image.jpg'); -> http://www.mydomain.it/images/image.jpg
image_url('image.jpg');    -> same as above
url(image-path('header.jpg'));  -> http://www.mydomain.it/images/image.jpg
asset-url('image.jpg', image); -> http://www.mydomain.it/image.jpg
```

problem still remains: assets are compiled but requested without digest.

**EDIT**

Following this question [Rails 4 image-path, image-url and asset-url no longer work in SCSS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843143/rails-4-image-path-image-url-and-asset-url-no-longer-work-in-scss-files?rq=1) I moved around my assets and using the combination of
asset-url and putting my assets in /public folder, background images are working, even though the problem still remains as the application is not using the timestamped version of the images.
So only a (not that good, nor that bad) workaround.

Comment: try once asset_url also.....in place of image_url

Comment: hm, i call it like this `image-url('whitey.png')` are you sure that it's `image_url`?

Comment: config.assets.enabled = true?

Comment: From rails guides: 

The asset pipeline is enabled by default. It can be disabled in config/application.rb by putting this line inside the application class definition:


`config.assets.enabled = false`,


but also tried it. And no success of course :)

Comment: Have you tried compiling your asset with `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`, I've had similar issues when using `rake assets:precompile` i.e. when using `RAILS_ENV=development`. Though I guess setting `config.assets.digest = true` should enable this...

Comment: Just to confirm that emaillenin's  solution actually works for me, but is really ugly. Using ERB on top of SCSS is ugly, as is copying non-fingerprinted resources or manually adding fingerprints.

Answer (score 4):

Should use `asset_path`. Also, it needs to run under ERB tag, as SCSS does not compile asset_path. Rename `common.scss` to `common.scss.erb`

```
.body { background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'bg.jpg' %>) }
```

Read more [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1209).

Comment: are you running in Development or production? asset_path has no effect in development. Check your Rails Env.

Comment: production env. Usign apache+passenger

Comment: capistrano is restarting the server at each deploy

Comment: assets:precompile again?

Comment: at each deploy capistrano recompiles the assets and restarts the server. that's what it is for :)

Comment: never used capistrano before :)

Comment: did u read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843143/rails-4-image-path-image-url-and-asset-url-no-longer-work-in-scss-files?rq=1)?

Comment: yes i did and the last try i did is to move my assets around... they're working if i move them in /public, using the asset-url('image.jpg', image) way. But the problem still remains, cause it's not the compiled version of the asset that the application in using..

Comment: try placing the output of `asset_path 'bg.jpg'` in a view script

Comment: are you getting fingerprint for any of the resources - css, js, fonts etc? or none at all. does it used to work earlier or this is the first time you are using asset pipeline?

Comment: I'm getting fingerprints for all the resources (js and css). Only image_url helpers (and similar) inside .scss files are not working

Comment: what is the helper method used to generate js path with fingerprint?

Comment: no helper methods, sprockets does it by itelf, just including `javascript_include_tag` in my application.html.erb file. This, with assets precompilation, results in digested assets urls

Comment: so this answer actually helped me: SCSS preprocessor does not correctly check if the referenced image has been appended a hash, and thus it cannot really be used this way. Adding ERB preprocessor to process SCSS before SCSS preprocessor solves this problem.

Comment: This is a great answer

Answer (score 2):

Some things to consider:

- Make sure the image is not "gitignored" or something
- Make sure the same image is not under public folder
- Make sure asset-related gems are directly in the Gemfile, and not under `group: :production` or something. This is the new rails norm
- Run `rake assets:clobber` and remove the `tmp` folder which contains sass cache
- Run `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` manually under production environment, and let us know the list of files generated under public
- Run `rake assets:precompile` in Development mode, it could provide more logs

Answer (score 1):

change your setting from this

```
config.serve_static_assets = false #also tried true
```

to

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

**Reason:** you are now allowing your assets to be called/served from your app. Earlier you aren't, it is currently served directly by your server i.e `apache` or `ngnix`.

I don't believe how this is possible

```
image-url('image.jpg'); -> http://www.mydomain.it/images/image.jpg
image_url('image.jpg');    -> same as above
url(image-path('header.jpg'));  -> http://www.mydomain.it/images/image.jpg
asset-url('image.jpg', image); -> http://www.mydomain.it/image.jpg
```

It should contain `assets` in place of `images`. if this is the case, there is something else going on apart from asset pipeline.

---

Since last time my question wasn't helpful so i thought to show you working app, i have created the heroku app (code is hosting on github). You can check all the commits. it is specially done for this question. The final fix is this.

Final fix: https://github.com/passion8/so2_fix/commit/64acc654d8926098ec5a40579f4a0e005037e381

Heroku URL: https://vast-plains-3919.herokuapp.com/

Github code: https://github.com/passion8/so2_fix

Github commits: https://github.com/passion8/so2_fix/commits/master

If this still doesn't work, make a look on

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25511960/1377943

Answer (score 1):

Either change the filename from `.css` to `.css.erb` and use `asset_url`:

```
background-image: url(<%= asset_url('x-icon.png')  %>);
```

Or you can use scss and do

```
background-image: url(asset-path('x-icon.png'));
```

Do not include "assets" in the path, i..e not `"assets/x-icon.png"`, this does not work.

To test this locally ensure your assets configuration mimics that of production, e.g.

```
      config.public_file_server.enabled  =  true      
      config.assets.compile              =  true
      config.assets.digest               =  true
```

Or if you start in production environment ensure `config.public_file_server.enabled = true` so the `public` directory is served by Rails, usually it would be served by Apache or similar.

- Rails 5.1

Comment: Cool. Works at Rails 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `common.scss` to `common.css.scss`

Read more: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing

Also, to add additional folders to asset pipeline add the following to config/environments/production.rb

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images')
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'stylesheets')
```

Comment: Assets are well precompiled, the problem is the generated path by image_url. Also tried to rename  the stylesheet but it has no effect

Answer (score 0):

I am using this and its work for me.
Use file with this format **common.css.scss**

```
.body 
{
    background:url(image_name.gif) no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

rails doesn't attach a digest for the assets that are not actually present so make sure that the images are already there in image directory.

Comment: images are well precompiled, put in public/assets folder, with a proper digest. the problem is the generated path in the stylesheet: it searches for not-compiled assets in the wrong place

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue here, I fixed it by Base 64 inlining the images using

> asset-data-url("images/image.jpg")

Answer (score 0):

use `image-url` in case of .scss as `image_url` works for .erb files.