# Rails 4 Heroku - changes not getting pushed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, amazon-s3, asset-pipeline

I am using Heroku to try to deploy a personal Ruby on Rails project and everything was going great until today.

I am very very new to Ruby on Rails and Heroku so please bare that in mind. I am not sure what is causing my issue and therefore not sure what code or information is best to supply so please ask me what you think you need to know to help resolve the issue and I will provide it.

My Ruby on Rails app worked fine both locally and on Heroku until I followed the information [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) to try and serve static images from Amazons S3 bucket. Note I only went as far as the static assets section.

This appeared to stop my Ruby on Rails application from recognising changes in my code. So I would make a change to a HTML file in my editor but the server was serving up the older version of the HTML file, even restarting the server didn't fix this.

I have been searching the web for hours trying to figure out what has gone wrong.

I deleted everything under public assets and I ran the precompile command:

> rake assets:precompile

And this seems to have improved things locally, when I edit a HTML file the changes are reflected on localhost. However when I push to Heroku and go to my application hosted on Heroku it still shows the older HTML file no matter how many changes I make and pushes I do to Heroku.

The HTML files that are not updating are located here:

> app/assets/templates

I'm not sure what I may have changed that has caused the HTML files not to get updated on Heroku?? What should I look at and try? What other information would be useful in helping track down the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer marked as correct in this StackOverflow question worked for me - [Updated CSS Stylesheet not loaded following deployment to Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455384/updated-css-stylesheet-not-loaded-following-deployment-to-heroku) - It looks like I accidently added assets precompiled file in my git repo somewhere along my development and that caused the issue.