# After upgrading to new Rails version few images are broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, imageurl

So my company updated Rails and Ruby versions, after that only few images became broken. They all defined in scss with `image_url("frontend/image_title.png")`, but only like 4 of them aren't showing anymore, server gives 404 error.
All of them used as a background images.

What could be a problem and a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried precompiling the assets ?

The call too `image_url` is done once during precompilation of assets so it could be that the assets in production still have old paths.

To precompile run the following command:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: Yes, we always do ```assets:clobber``` and ```assets:precompile```, but only those 4 images are 404'ed.

Comment: What is the full path in the markup/asset when you inspect it in the browser ?

Comment: One more thing I suggest looking here if you haven't already seen it. It is pretty compressive and covers most areas to check. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650699/rails4-image-url-not-generating-digest-in-scss

Comment: In browser it looks for assets at my site, like ```mysite.com/assets/etc```, but it should look at the amazon bucket, like all the other images works, except for those.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i will always answer my own questions :)

The problem was that there are few .scss files that was compiling with assets pipeline, and those .scss files had some same code, like scss variables and reset code, which i decided to move out of them to separate file, called `reset.css.scss` and import that file into those .scss files with `@import` function, which works bad with Rails `*= require` methods.

After moving that code back to .scss files and removing the `@import` stuff, everything worked fine.

Comment: actually it appears again now when another person doing assets clobbering and compilation, so question is still open :(