# In rails 5 @font-face custom css is not working after I put fonts in assets's font folder?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts

I am using font-awesome custom css but it is not working in my rails application.

I am getting this error:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2"):

added font In assets's stylesheet folder make style.css

```
@font-face { font-family: 'ProximaNovaA-Light'; src: 
url('ProximaNovaA-Light.otf') format('opentype'), 
url('ProximaNovaA-Light.woff') format('woff'), 
url('ProximaNovaA-Light.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('ProximaNovaA-Light.ttf') format('truetype'), 
url('ProximaNovaA-Light.svg#ProximaNovaA-Light') format('svg'); 
font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }
```

I think this is a path issue, how can we fix it?

Comment: Please add code where did you added font .

Comment: In assets's stylesheet folder make style.css


@font-face {
  font-family: 'ProximaNovaA-Light';
  src:  url('ProximaNovaA-Light.otf')  format('opentype'),
       url('ProximaNovaA-Light.woff') format('woff'),
       url('ProximaNovaA-Light.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), 
       url('ProximaNovaA-Light.ttf')  format('truetype'), 
       url('ProximaNovaA-Light.svg#ProximaNovaA-Light') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

Comment: Where is your font located ?

Comment: Made Fonts folder in assets folder and put them.

Comment: try this `font-family: '/assets/ProximaNovaA-Light'; src: 
url('/assets/ProximaNovaA-Light.otf') format('opentype')`

Comment: yes this is perfect ....!

Comment: i will add answer for it. please accept that answer so it will helpful to other users. will you accept and upvote it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
font-family: '/assets/ProximaNovaA-Light';
src: url('/assets/ProximaNovaA-Light.otf') format('opentype')
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

change that file to `.erb` and

```
url('fontawesome-webfont.woff2')
```

to

```
url(<%= asset_path 'fontawesome-webfont.woff2' %>)
```

or install the [fontawesome gem](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails)

### Explanation

`url('ProximaNovaA-Light.otf')` is not working.

This is my url in the `browser developer tools sources` tab. I display `url`

[image]

This the detail of my code, as you can see I commented `url()` tags and uset the `asset_path` erb helper

[image]

As you have a runtime error you can not check the url, but the message says that your url is `/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2`.

As you see my url is `/assets/ElegantIcons-912b4fcc232e1f45d329e2a127bca4bdf3195d965a2abce223b068e3c3c7db6a.eot`, because the idea of the asset pipeline is pre-compiling assets with a digest.

The digest is the code `912b4fcc232e1f45d329e2a127bca4bdf3195d965a2abce223b068e3c3c7db6a` that identifies the asset in my folder `/public/assets`, where a temporary copy of my stylesheets, javascripts, images are saved.

That is the location where files are saved and read (`/public/assets`).
The `url()` helper is not converting the relative path `/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2` for the file `app/asset/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2` into `public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-digestcode.woff2`

Actually this is a big issue with Rails Asset Pipeline discussed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638989/rails-3-1-asset-urls-in-scss-files-do-not-seem-to-be-referencing-the-assets-corr).

The other scenario is that you do not have that image.

This is the code I used in my custom fonts file `elegant-icons-style.scss.erb` to import those images.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ElegantIcons';
    src: url(<%= asset_path 'ElegantIcons.eot' %>),
         url(<%= asset_path 'ElegantIcons.eot?#iefix' %>) format('embedded-opentype'),
         url(<%= asset_path 'ElegantIcons.woff' %>) format('woff'),
         url(<%= asset_path 'ElegantIcons.ttf' %>) format('truetype'),
         url(<%= asset_path 'ElegantIcons.svg' %>) format('svg');
    /*src: url('/assets/ElegantIcons.eot');
    src: url('/assets/ElegantIcons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/assets/ElegantIcons.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/assets/ElegantIcons.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/assets/ElegantIcons.svg#ElegantIcons') format('svg');*/
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change that `mycssfile.css` file to `mycssfile.css.erb`

(add `.erb` end of file, then you can use rails code in `.css.erb` file)

and in `mycssfile.css.erb` file, change:

```
url('fontawesome-webfont.woff2')
```

to

```
url(<%= asset_path 'fontawesome-webfont.woff2' %>)
```

Final code in `.css.erb` file:

```
@font-face { font-family: 'ProximaNovaA-Light'; src: 
url(<%= asset_path 'ProximaNovaA-Light.otf' %>) format('opentype'), 
url(<%= asset_path 'ProximaNovaA-Light.woff' %>) format('woff'), 
url(<%= asset_path 'ProximaNovaA-Light.eot' %>) format('embedded-opentype'),
url(<%= asset_path 'ProximaNovaA-Light.ttf' %>) format('truetype'), 
url(<%= asset_path 'ProximaNovaA-Light.svg' %>#ProximaNovaA-Light) format('svg'); 
font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }
```