# "No route matches" when view an image

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the file "test.gif" in the "/images". In the view, I am using the following command to view it

```
<%= image_tag 'test.gif' %>
```

which renders

```
<img src="/images/test.gif" alt="Test">
```

But the image is not displayed. Going to "src" address, I get the error message:

```
No route matches [GET] "/images/test.gif"
```

How to solve this problem?

**Edit:**

My `route.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :products
end
```

Comment: Have you tried `<%= image_tag image_path('test.gif') %>`?

Comment: I've tried it and did not solve the problem

Comment: show your routes file

Comment: get '/images/test.gif' => 'images#test.gif' put this in your routes nd try

Comment: @NitinRajan In this way, I get the error message "uninitialized constant ImagesController"

Comment: add your controller code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843143/rails-4-image-path-image-url-and-asset-url-no-longer-work-in-scss-files will help you

Comment: Is it inside **public/images** or **assets/images**? If inside **assets/images** then image `src` should look like "/assets/test.gif"

Comment: Have you turned on your static assets?

Comment: I'm using the folder "public/images"

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<%= asset_path('test.gif') %>
```

Comment: I've tried using this command and moving the image to the root, but did not solve the problem.

Comment: You shouldn't need to move it in your root directory. Leaving it inside the images folder should still work

Comment: Sorry. I meant "copied". I have the same image in the images directory as well. And that does not render the HTML code to display the image, so I tried with `<%= image_tag asset_path('test.gif') %>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Take the slash out in front of the images

```
<img src="images/test.gif" alt="Test">
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem.

It is mandatory to use the folders `/app/assets` or `/public`. Other beyond this Rails does not allow.
So I copied the image to `/public/test.gif` and used the command

```
<%= image_tag '/uploads/test.gif' %>
```