# image from asset pipeline not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I need to insert a photo from my asset pipeline into my rails project. I am using a template from bootstrap (http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/clean-blog/)

The photo isn't showing up. Here is my code:

```
<!-- Set your background image for this header on the line below. -->
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: image_url('home-bg.jpg')">
```

I looked here: [Rails 4 image-path, image-url and asset-url no longer work in SCSS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843143/rails-4-image-path-image-url-and-asset-url-no-longer-work-in-scss-files) and I tried every combination on the page, and it still doesn't work. When I do this:

```
  http://localhost:3000/assets/home-bg.jpg
```

then the photo does show in my browser. I have a feeling that it could be a problem from the css stylesheets I imported with the template, but I don't know any css at all so don't really know where to start in that way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your ruby code is not being interpolated (interpreted). You must use "erb tags". Try this:

```
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: <%= image_url('home-bg.jpg') %>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to try `asset_path` or `asset_url`.

```
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'home-bg.jpg' %>)">
```